What documents do I need to to fly alone to Germany as a 15 year old from India?
I am planning on traveling to Germany from India alone during the summer of 2025 to see my relatives. What documents do I need to apply for a Schengen visa as an Indian minor?

This question is similar to: Schengen visa application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. As a minor intending to visit relatives in Germany proving intention to leave may be a challenge and you will need parental consent.

@Traveller this is distinct from the alleged duplicate because it asks for information specific for traveling as a minor

Other than the usual set of documents for adults, you need to get permission letter from both your parents, probably the copy of their passports as well, to establish the relationship. You also needed an invitation letter from the relatives you are planning to stay with, mentioning that they will take care of you and expenses encountered.
See this answer for general directions: Schengen visa application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?

You will need several documents to apply for a Schengen visa. These include a valid passport with at least two blank pages and valid for three months beyond your stay, a visa application form signed by both parents or legal guardians, and a parental consent letter allowing you to travel alone. You'll also need your birth certificate as proof of relationship, flight itinerary, proof of accommodation, travel insurance covering your stay, and proof of financial means from your relatives or parents. Additionally, an invitation letter from your relatives in Germany is required. It's best to check with the German consulate for any specific requirements.
